# Issue with JQuery Sparkline in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins

I used jQuery sparkline (http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/) in a page. This gives me problem in IE if the container DIV is not big enough to show it, tried with Firefox/Chrome, it is working fine. See the sample code,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var myvalues = [10,8,5,7,4,4,1];
        $('.dynamicsparkline').sparkline(myvalues, {height:'100px',width:'300px'});
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:100px;width:400px;overflow:auto;border:1px solid black">
          Testing Header
          <br/>
          <span class="dynamicsparkline">Loading..</span>
          <br/>
          Testing Footer
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing with IE? I'm able to run it in Firefox 3.5RC2, Chrome and IE 8 and IE 7 (emulation in IE8) with similar results.

Comment: the chart is drawn on top of everything, it is not considering the overflow property of the containing div

Comment: screen shot added here
http://download.yousendit.com/UmNJTkZyTEQ5NVVLSkE9PQ

Comment: I am using IE7, checked with IE8, it is working but not in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gareth Watts(http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/) helped me to solve this issue by adding "position:relative" to the container div.

here is the code

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var myvalues = [10,8,5,7,4,4,1];
        $('.dynamicsparkline').sparkline(myvalues, {height:'100px',width:'300px'});
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:100px;width:400px;overflow:auto;border:1px solid black;position: relative">
          Testing Header
          <br/>
          <span class="dynamicsparkline">Loading..</span>
          <br/>
          Testing Footer
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It can be reproduced only in IE7.

Thanks